# How to avoid deadlock situation in insert into select with update on duplicate?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am facing deadlock issue on a table when using bulk insert, the query is below

```
INSERT INTO registrationupdates (refreshtime,firstseentime,userdevice,isexist,userpart,expires,ipaddress,contacturi,deviceid)
SELECT refreshtime,firstseentime,userdevice,isexist,userpart,expires,ipaddress,contacturi,(SELECT IFNULL(id,0) FROM devicedetails WHERE deviceip LIKE CONCAT('%',registrarip , '%'))
FROM register_temp_table  WHERE isexist=1  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `refreshtime`=VALUES(refreshtime),`firstseentime`=VALUES(firstseentime),`userdevice`=VALUES(userdevice),`isexist`=VALUES(isexist);
```

Am getting the below error message

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

'contacturi' is the unique key and have indexing on userpart column on registrationupdates table.

Can anyone really help me on this please ?

Comment: see [How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate this into two queries to avoid inserting and selecting the same table in a single query.

I think it may solve your problem in avoiding deadlock condition

Comment: how this can be separated ?

Comment: Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470185/how-to-avoid-deadlock-in-mysql.

Comment: Did you get what you need?

Comment: will this work for bulk select ? I just checked that link but there used limit 1.